# Arrangement of column next to last Nth instance of delimiter

Tags: columns

I have the following data in my `file`

```
alice bob cathy david elon
unix linux bsd
```

---

I want output with **only the last Nth instance** of delimiter  (ie. a space) being arranged

Like for **last instance** of delimiter  (space)

```
alice bob cathy david     elon
unix linux                bsd
```

or for **second last instance** of delimiter  (space)

```
alice bob cathy     david elon
unix                linux bsd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your data is delimited by `:`:

```
perl -F'[:]' -lane '
   push @e, join $", splice @F, -1;
   push @A, join $", @F;
   length($A[-1]) > $maxW and $maxW = length($A[-1])}{
   print $_, $" x ($maxW - length), "\t", shift @e for @A;
' file
```

---

## Results

```
alice bob cathy david   elon
unix linux              bsd
```

---

when you want the last 2 elements to be separated, then change the `-1` in the `splice` arguments list to `-2`, resulting in:

---

```
alice bob cathy david elon
unix            linux bsd
```

---

## Explanation

- Maintain the array `@e` that holds the last-Nth elements for each line.
- Maintain the array `@A` that holds eachh line after the last-N elements have been pruned from the current line.
- We determine the maximum width of these pruned lines.
- After all lines have been read, we print each pruned line + differential spaces such that pruned-line lengths are equalized (after right padding spaces) + TAB + last-N elements.

Comment: How do I change delimiter from space to any other thing like `(` or `:`

Comment: I did not understand, could you please add an example in your answer replacing spaces with `:` delimiter in the file and then your code ? Thank you for helping.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I've modified the answer. Note however, the output is still space separated and not ":" separated.